# Entity Framework Not Updating Datastore?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Using EF with a SQL datastore, the datastore is not updating with the correct data. Here is my code portion for how i create the wrapper object and the relevant function that should update. I think my issue has something to do with the lifecycle of the entity context?  But shouldn't re-attaching the object to the context before saving it resolve any issues?

```
Public Sub New(ByVal UserID As Integer)
    Using Context As New RiseDB.RiseDBContainer
        MyUser = Context.Users.Find(UserID)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function Save() As Boolean
    Using Context As New RiseDB.RiseDBContainer
        Context.Users.Attach(MyUser)
        Context.SaveChanges()
    End Using
    Return True
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    If Not IsNothing(Context) Then
        Context.SaveChanges()
        Context.Dispose()
        Context = Nothing
    End If
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
```

The function that should set a property:

```
Public Shared Function PasswordChanged(ByVal UserID As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim tmp As New User(UserID)
    tmp.IsPasswordReset = False
    tmp.Save()
    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you execute the Save function? What version of EF are you using? Which version of .NET?  Ans Visual Studio?

Comment: No error was given. EF: 6.1 VS 2012, .net 4.5.  The datastore will just not update to the new value if i try to re-attach the object and save changes. The best work-around i came up with since edit-save operations are short lived, was to open a context and not detach or reattach the object until it has been saved.